# Qt 5, QML 2.0 and transparent borderless window incompatibility

Tags: c++, qt, qml, transparent, qtstylesheets

Tasks:

1. Rounded-corners window
2. Custom borders
3. QML in QWidget

---

1. Because there is no way to change border style in parent widget, I made two of them.  First parent widget is transparent, it's set in QSS. Second one is the one with rounded-corners, also set in QSS. p.s. I guess it isn't smartest idea. Not even close.
   To make it work, I've set up Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground attribute.
2. Set up Qt::FramelessWindowHint window flag.
3. QML 2.0 style.[in code below]

So problem is:

When WA_TranslucentBackground and FramelessWindowHint is on - NO QML

When FramelessWindowHint is on - Only QML view

When WA_TranslucentBackground or both are off - still system BORDERS

Also I've tried to set mask on MainWindow

```
QPixmap pixmap = QWidget::grab(this->rect());
this->setMask(pixmap.createMaskFromColor(Qt::transparent, Qt::MaskInColor));
```

Works well, no system borders, custom one is rounded and QML works, but whole other area became white, don't know how to fix.

MainWindow:

```
QFile styleFile("style.qss");
styleFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly), qApp->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String(styleFile.readAll()));

QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(new QQuickView(QUrl("main.qml")), this);
ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(container);

//this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
//this->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::Window);
QPixmap pixmap = QWidget::grab(this->rect());
this->setMask(pixmap.createMaskFromColor(Qt::transparent, Qt::MaskInColor));
```

Styles:

```
QWidget#MainWindow{
background:transparent;
}

QWidget#MainWindowRounded{
background-color: grey;
border: 1px solid black;    
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Is this possible to resolve?

[***HERE SOURCE CODE***](https://mega.co.nz/#!k15UibgA!qXIR0cLRsIP-v5c8N9YXnhKC-nsNErwO5YW2JyMQbqY)